# Apollo-Engine HTTPS

Tags: node.js, apollo, apollo-server, express-graphql

Is there a way, that engine is listening for nodes HTTPS-Server?

I only found:

```
    engine.listen({
     port: 3000,
     httpServer: server,
    });
```

in the documentation.

When I want to send some queries, I get an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now supported as of apollo-engine@1.1.0! See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/engine/setup-node.html#https for details.